# Http 404 error while starting apache server

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat

I run the server Apache Tomcat - after installing Eclipse and Tomcat on a new computer - in Eclipse and haven't any problem: INFO: Server startup in 575 ms. But when I type "http://localhost:8080/", I didn't get the Apache Tomcat Home Page, but get the following error message : HTTP Status 404 error in tomcat, The requested resource is not avaliable.
Whts the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tomcat is already running. But it is not able to find the resource for Apache Home Page.
As you are running the server from eclipse and eclipse doesn't copy the tomcat "ROOT"folder (where the welcome/index pages are) , therefore you need to manually copy the "ROOT" folder from your
 `{tomcat directory}\webapps` .Copy and then go to your Eclipse workspace, go to the `.metadata` folder, and search for "wtpwebapps". You should find something like `your-eclipse-workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps` (or .../tmp1/wtpwebapps if you already had another server registered in Eclipse). Go to the wtpwebapps folder, paste/merge  ROOT. Then reload `"http://localhost:8080/"` to see the Tomcat welcome page.

Comment: great that just worked for me.....thnx..but now when i click on the manager app again i am getting the same http 404 erro...but i can now work on that with eclipse...

Comment: @harshil-shah http://stackoverflow.com/a/6782113/1085285  If you want to make all tomcat webapss work . you have to either change server location path to tomcat directory in eclipse . or you can manually add other webapps on modules page. (both of these setting can be found by double clicking on server in the eclipse.)