# I cannot access tomcat admin console?

Tags: tomcat7

I am try to build an app with the integration of JPA and Struts. to do it need to access tomcat manager. But when I access URL **`http://localhost:8080/manager/html`** it gives 404 Error to me.

My **tomcat-users.xml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='cp1252'?>

  <tomcat-users>

    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>

    <!--<user name="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status" />-->
    <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status"/>

    </tomcat-users>
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://localhost:8080 does it give you the Yes it work page ? do you have another server running on the 8080 ?

Comment: Windows:

I am using Eclipse. I had to copy the manager/ folder from C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\webapps to my Eclipse workspace (~\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\).

Answer (score 11):

Your `tomcat-users.xml` looks good.

**Make sure you have the `manager/` application inside your `$CATALINA_BASE/webapps/`**

- Linux:

You have to install tomcat-admin package: `sudo apt-get install tomcat8-admin` (for version 8)

- Windows:

I am using Eclipse. I had to copy the `manager/` folder from `C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.20\webapps` to my Eclipse workspace (`~\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\`).

Answer (score 3):

Notice that the http code response status you are getting is an HTTP 404. The 404 or Not Found error message is a response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested.

If you have got an 403 Forbidden vs 401 Unauthorized HTTP responses then it might  make a sense to review your tomcat-users.xml.

Resuming: check the manager resources and files of your server installation, some file/directory might be missing, or the path to the manager resources has been changed.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps manager app does not exist
look if you the manager application is on $APACHE_HOME/server/webapps directory.
on this directory you must have : docs,examples, host-manager,manager, ROOT.

Answer (score 2):

If you are running tomcat from eclipse (probably problem exists with another IDEs), it could have a different configuration- not based on files .

The solution is to edit tomcat users file, as you wrote, and then start tomcat from command prompt with

```
{tomcat-directory}/bin/startup
```

Answer (score 1):

This is all I did and restarted the server.

```
<tomcat-users>

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, it just was that service console restart didn't work after tomcat ran into an error. Only stop/start brought it back.