# Tomcat manager HTTP Status 404 - /manager/html

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat6

I am working on apache-tomcat-6.0.35. When I start tomcat using the startup.sh manually tomcat is just working fine.

I want to configure tomcat to use with eClipse. And I did by adding a new server to eclipse and when I start Tomcat by hitting localhost:8080 , it starts fine but when I try to navigate to manager HTTP Status 404 - /manager/html . Basically I cant navigate to any link in tomcat.

As I mentioned it works fine when I start tomcat from the startup.sh script

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display the Tomcat Manager Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6776421/display-the-tomcat-manager-application)

Comment: Please see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49691898/3127111) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6776421/3127111).

Answer (score 6):

You're probably using your workspace metadata as the server and deploy path, where the manager simply isn't available.

Switch to using the Tomcat installation and it should work (the manager application resides in the webapps/-directory inside the Tomcat installation).

To do that, double click the server name in the `Servers`-Tab, and activate `Use Tomcat installation`. To be able to do that you might have to remove all deployed webapps and `Clean` the server.

[image]