# Where does Tomcat in Eclipse store the expanded WAR?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

When I launch my web application from Eclipse Indigo, where does Tomcat 7 store web application folder? It is not located in Tomcat's own webapp folder. Why I can not access Tomcat's default home page (I talk about http://localhost:8080), if it started under Eclipse? If I start tomcat manually (thruogh the `startup.bat`), I can access http://localhost:8080.

Comment: You need to supply more details.  You are just trying to setup eclipse to run with tomcat, correct?  What steps did you take to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Doubleclick the Tomcat server entry in *Servers* view and check the *Server Locations* section. The path is in there and you can also configure in there if Eclipse should use the Tomcat installation instead of the workspace metadata (which is the default setting).

[image]

Note that the server must be published with no modules present to make changes. I.e. stop the server, remove all projects and publish the server.

[image]

This will also make the Tomcat homepage available.

#### See also:

- [Tomcat started in Eclipse but unable to connect to http://localhost:8085/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280064/tomcat-started-in-eclipse-but-unable-to-connect-to-link-to-http-localhost8085)

Answer (score 4):

Per default it will deploy your application in a subfolder of .metadata-folder from your workspace.

Comment: Thanks! More precisely under:
.../workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/