# Where does Eclipse place the .war file?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jersey

I'm new to Java EE web development. I've created a JAX-RS based web application in Eclipse which I'm running on Tomcat. The project has dependencies managed by Maven. Everything is working fine. However now if I have to ship this project, I'd assume I would have to provide a .war file to the user.

So here's my questions:

1. Where does eclipse place this war file?
2. Will this file have everything in it, in the right order to run as web application or do  I need to provide any other file in addition, like web.xml or pom.xml?
3. If the user of the application has downloaded tomcat, does all he/she needs to do it copy the .war file into the Tomcat directory and right-click to run?

Answer (score 3):

1. Eclipse deploys WAR to the tomcat. Exact place depends on your tomcat settings. See details here: [Where does Tomcat in Eclipse store the expanded WAR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8197250/where-does-tomcat-in-eclipse-store-the-expanded-war)
   You mentioned a pom.xml file so you probably use some maven plugin (like this https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/) to build the war file. Refer the plugin documentation to understand how to configure the war artifact creation.
2. Everything is inside (in your case the project is properly configured in maven). You should just deploy to the server.
3. You should not right click or whatever. Just place into the webapps folder in the tomcat installation or deploy via manager app. I gues you should read the documentation here https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html to understand what is deployment and how to do it.

One more useful link:http://www.codejava.net/ides/eclipse/eclipse-create-deployable-war-file-for-java-web-application

Answer (score 2):

right click in project > export > web project > .war
Then copy the .war file into webapp directory of your apache tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

If you use maven and you configured it properly the easiest way to create your war is to call:

$ mvn clean install

in your project directory, in the location of pom.xml.
After that you will find generated war in:
    path_to_your_project/targe/your_application.war

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse does not put anything anywhere itself. When you build the project using maven, according to maven folder structure it will build and put the war file in its target directory where the project is present in file system (mostly inside your workspace), which you can see on your eclipse package/project explorer.

Try building your project using mvn clean package

If all your dependencies has scope 'compile' in POM.xml then maven will push those corresponding jars to web-inf/lib, but if you have 'provided' scope then you have to put those JARs in sever by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

```
Even I am new to J2EE Web Application development.
I am using Tomcat 8.0.27 and Eclipse Luna.
From my trial and error, I have noticed that after successful Maven Build creation (pom.XML --> Run As (4 Maven Clean OR 6 Maven Install); the war file is saved in the user folder as below.

C:\Users\username\\.m2\repository\com\i4\I4Connect\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\I4Connect-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war

In the fore mentioned folder 
(C:\Users\username\\.m2\repository\com\i4\I4Connect\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\); I also see the following files along with the mentioned war file.
1. _remote.repositories --> Repositories file
2. I4Connect-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom --> POM file
3. maven-metadata-local --> XML file

Hope this helps.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hello Again,

what i realized was, the war file created earlier was a snapshot.
However, when I closely tracked the build creation again, I noticed that eclipse provides details of every step of the build creation that could be observed in the console.
Following is snapshot of what I got when I re-created the build.
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] Using the builder org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder with a thread count of 1
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building I4Connect Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ I4Connect ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 6 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ I4Connect ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ I4Connect ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1252 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\EclipseProjectWorkspace\iConnectDev\I4Connect\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ I4Connect ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ I4Connect ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ I4Connect ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [I4Connect] in [D:\EclipseProjectWorkspace\iConnectDev\I4Connect\target\I4Connect]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [D:\EclipseProjectWorkspace\iConnectDev\I4Connect\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [22881 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: ***D:\EclipseProjectWorkspace\iConnectDev\I4Connect\target\I4Connect.war***
[INFO] WEB-INF\web.xml already added, skipping
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ I4Connect ---
[INFO] Installing D:\EclipseProjectWorkspace\iConnectDev\I4Connect\target\I4Connect.war to C:\Users\hareesh.s\.m2\repository\com\i4\I4Connect\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\I4Connect-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] Installing D:\EclipseProjectWorkspace\iConnectDev\I4Connect\pom.xml to C:\Users\hareesh.s\.m2\repository\com\i4\I4Connect\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\I4Connect-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 59.929 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-02-28T11:31:11+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 11M/125M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
******************************************************************************
******************************************************************************
As can be gathered, the war file is created in the Workspace folder.
D:\EclipseProjectWorkspace\iConnectDev\I4Connect\target\I4Connect.war
```