# How to handle special chars in parameter values?

Tags: java, servlets, encoding

I've some issues with my *Java Servlet* if it's called with special chars (like Æ, Ø og Å) in the GET-parameters: http://localhost:8080/WebService/MyService?test=Øst.

I than have this code in my `doGet`:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println(request.getParameterValues("test")[0]);
}
```

The messages printed in the console is: *Ã?st*.

The Web Service should be able to handle calls like this. How can I encode the parameter values in a proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This needs to be configured at servet level. It's not clear which one you're using, so I'll give examples for Tomcat and Glassfish only.

**Tomcat**: add `URIEncoding` attribute to `<Connector>` element in `/conf/server.xml`:

```xml
<Connector ... URIEncoding="UTF-8">
```

**Glassfish**: add `<parameter-encoding>` to `/WEB-INF/glassfish-web.xml` (or `sun-web.xml` for older versions):

```xml
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8" />
```

#### See also:

- [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html) - [JSP/Servlet request](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html#JSPServletRequest)

Comment: I'm using a Tomcat server using the Eclipse IDE. The file *WebContent/WEB-INF/web.xml* does not contain any Connector-element. Is it normal?

Comment: I said `/conf/server.xml`, not `/WEB-INF/web.xml`. It's in Tomcat installation folder. However, if you haven't taken over Tomcat fully in Eclipse (which is the default setting; see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280064/tomcat-started-in-eclipse-but-unable-to-connect-to-link-to-http-localhost8085/2280798#2280798), then you need to configure it by the `server.xml` in *Servers* project instead. Note that for production Tomcat this needs to be configured in its `/conf/server.xml`.

Answer (score 1):

you should be percent encoding special characters (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).  In your example above, the "slashed O" (Ø) has the UTF-8 code 0xd8, so your URL would properly be written:

http://localhost:8080/WebService/MyService?test=%d8st.

Which should result in

```
Øst.
```

being printed to the console, from your servlet code above.

Comment: A service like Google Maps works without percent encoding special chars: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=9220+Aalborg+Øst&destination=Copenhagen&sensor=false&region=dk. I would like to support this too.

Answer (score -1):

You could try the following code before requesting parameters:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

Comment: That's for POST requests only.