# How to pass json object with special characters to servlet?

Tags: json, servlets

I want to pass json values to the servlet to handle the request.

In client side, i could made the object with special character such as "&" .

I have given the input as

```
"<h3>Welcome to ERP your name is #NAME#</h3>\n\n<h3>&nbsp;</h3>\n"
```

I retrieve the value from the json object by using

```
request.getParameter("jsonVal")
```

by calling like this, the json value after the "&nbsp" , not taken by the servlet. The output is

```
"\"<h3>Welcome to ERP your name is #NAME#</h3>\\n\\n<h3>
```

and shows the error as:

```
org.json.JSONException: Unterminated string at character 206
at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextString(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(Unknown Source)
at erp.controller.Controller.doPost(Controller.java:49)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

How to handle this issue?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804618/how-to-handle-special-chars-in-parameter-values) .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275359/jquery-single-quote-in-json-response

Comment: Sorry. that is not worked.

Answer (score 0):

After getting request.getParameter("jsonVal") , try on a JSON Viewer and identify what is the special character. Carriage return+new line has issues with JSONTokener, so you can trim it if possible and work with it.