# HTTP Status 404 - / Error when i started first time

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I just have installed `Eclipse` and `Apache tomcat 7.0.35` and add as a server in Eclipse. I ran localhost:8080/ that gave me the following **error :**

```
HTTP Status 404 - / 
type Status report
message /
description The requested resource is not available.    
Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
```

Plz help me solve this issue.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This seem to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11003135/http-status-404-localhost8080-when-trying-to-install-apache-tomcat-in-e?rq=1

Comment: what do you mean by trying? i have nothing deployed yet..

Comment: I mean what have you explored as a possible error this far? What did google say when you search for the error symptoms etc. There are a bunch of questions regarding this on StackOverflow have you tried any of the solutions described in them?

Comment: possible duplicate of [TOMCAT - HTTP Status 404](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340711/tomcat-http-status-404)

Comment: I have tried to both of the solutions that u mentioned saying duplicated. Then an error arises " Publishing the configuration...
Error copying file to C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Tomcat 7.0/backup\catalina.policy: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\backup\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified) bla bla bla..."

Comment: Looks like your `...\backup\catalina.policy` does not exist. Basically I would assume your installation of Tomcat is corrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Tomcat is telling you that you don't have a default application. Typically when you install Tomcat, it will come with a ROOT default application, which you will find in the webapps directory. If there is no ROOT application in the webapps directory, and you address the root of the Tomcat web server, Tomcat will report a HTTP 404 error.