# HTTP Status 404 - Servlet [ServletName] is not available

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

**The problem** : My index.jsp with web.xml keeps going into HTTP 404 and 500

I'm using Tomcat6 .

This is from index.jsp :

```html
  <legend>Registration</legend>
  <form action="./register"> <%-- Address from web.xml  --%>
    First name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
    Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
  </form>
```

When I'm in Registration :

[image]

and I hit the name and last-name , I go into 404 , the message :

> ### HTTP Status 404 - Servlet RegistrationServlet is not available
>
> **type** Status report
>
> **message** Servlet RegistrationServlet is not available
>
> **description** The requested resource (Servlet RegistrationServlet is not available) is not available.
>
> Apache Tomcat/6.0.35

What do you think it the cause for that error ?

The class `RegistrationServlet` is under the file `RegistrationServlet.java` in the folder `src/coreservlets/`

I checked web.xml but it seems to be okay , but here it is (if it would be helpful):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd" version="2.4">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ShowBalance</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>coreservlets.ShowBalance</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ShowBalance</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/show-balance</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RandomNumberServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>coreservlets.RandomNumberServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RandomNumberServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/random-number</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegistrationServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>coreservlets.RegistrationServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegistrationServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>PrimeServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>coreservlets.PrimeServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PrimeServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/prime</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I've been trying to fix this little culprit for the last two days but nothing , any help would be much appreciated .

**EDIT:**

As requested , here is `RegistrationServlet`

```
package coreservlets;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class RegistrationServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        synchronized (session) {
            NameBean nameBean = (NameBean) session.getAttribute("name");
            if (nameBean == null) {
                nameBean = new NameBean();
                session.setAttribute("name", nameBean);
            }
            nameBean.setFirstName(request.getParameter("firstName"));
            nameBean.setLastName(request.getParameter("lastName"));
            String address = "/WEB-INF/mvc-sharing/ShowName.jsp";
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request
                    .getRequestDispatcher(address);
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
}
```

Also here is the project tree :

[image]

Comment: In your form action ,try changing './register' to '/register' (remove the dot)

Comment: Try `<form method='post' action="/register">`

Comment: what is your absolute application URL?

Comment: @ftom2: I got this : `HTTP Status 404 - /register

type Status report

message /register

description The requested resource (/register) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35`

Comment: @ITCuties: Tried that and got this : `HTTP Status 404 - /register

type Status report

message /register

description The requested resource (/register) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/6.0.35`

Comment: What does server log say? Is there anything?

Comment: can any 1 review this problem for me please....

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29312999/http-status-404-liangweb-timeform

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your URL is completely fine. If the URL was wrong, you would have gotten a 404 message like follows:

> Requested resource `register` is not available

But you instead got

> Servlet `RegistrationServlet` is not available

This means that the servlet was found, but that it couldn't be executed because its construction and initialization failed with an exception. Under Tomcat's covers, *basically* one of the following steps has failed:

```
Servlet servlet = new RegistrationServlet();
servlet.init(servletConfig);
servlet.init();
```

You need to read the server logs for this exception and then fix the code accordingly.

---

Whilst your URL is completely fine, it's error prone to changes in the context. You'd rather like to specify a domain-relative URL instead:

```html
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register">
```

See also this related answer: [Browser can't access/find relative resources like CSS, images and links when calling a Servlet which forwards to a JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655316/browser-cant-access-css-and-images-when-calling-a-servlet-which-forwards-to-a-j/3658735#3658735)

Comment: I am noob so have mercy but i have stupid question. Is it possible for Tomcat to use jsp files placed in WEB-INF in eclipse?

Comment: @Pshemo: Yes. That's even the recommended practice in MVC. Only a servlet can forward to them by `RequestDispatcher`. This way users are forced to use a front controller servlet to access the JSP and can never access those JSPs individually for which a pre/post processing servlet is required. See also our servlets wiki page to learn about using servlets: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info

Comment: Thank you very much. Sorry I'm thanking so late but I needed to test what you told me to make sure i understood you correctly :)

Comment: @BalusC: Thank you very much for the help with my last posts . Second ,I've tried to use this `<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/register">
` but I still get `404` page like that `HTTP Status 404 - Servlet RegistrationServlet is not available

type Status report

message Servlet RegistrationServlet is not available

description The requested resource (Servlet RegistrationServlet is not available) is not available.` . Where can I find the logs ?

Comment: @BalusC: Okay , then I got this `HTTP Status 500 -

type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

javax.servlet.ServletException: Wrapper cannot find servlet class coreservlets.RegistrationServlet or a class it depends on` , meaning that it can't find the class . How can I fix this ? this is so annoying :)

Comment: Please read the server startup log, not the HTTP 500 error page. In Eclipse, it's just in the console which appears when you start the server.

Comment: @BalusC: Okay ,so here it is : I've moved from `tomcat6` to `tomcat7` so no more `web.xml` . When I run the project from inside of Eclipse , it works great ! But when I create a `WAR` file and try to run using `localhost:8080/mvc` it just go crazy and starts all over again with page `404` & `500` . Then , what might cause this ? why I can run successfully from inside Eclipse but can't run just the same when using `WAR` file ? thanks again , you've helped a lot !

Comment: If you create a WAR and manually deploy to Tomcat, you need to manually start Tomcat using its `startup` script instead of doing it by Eclipse, with the simple reason because the manually deployed WAR is not under control of Eclipse. Eclipse does by default not use Tomcat's deploy folder, but instead uses its engine and deploys into workspace. For some background and configuration see also this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2280798/157882

Comment: @BalusC: This is exactly what I did so far . I'm using tomcat with Xampp , I exported the `WAR` file to `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 7.0\webapps` and then executed from Chrome this line `http://localhost:8080/nameOfMyProject` , but after reaching the `Registration` page , all over again the `404` & `500` are back

Comment: You need to read server log of that Tomcat instance then in its `/logs` folder (assuming that Xampp hasn't modified its default trim; I have never used Xampp, so I can't tell that). Note that this doesn't appear in Eclipse at all as it's completely out of control of Eclipse.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13310/discussion-between-ron-and-balusc)

Answer (score 1):

Err... this is obvious, but is RegistrationServlet.class in /WEB-INF/classes/coreservlets/? Did you compile? (With Tomcat, do you NEED to compile explicitly? It'd be surprising if you did not.)

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the path to register is not accounting for the context path. A good way to fix this would be to use the jstl core url tag -

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
...
<c:url value="/register" var="url">
<form action="${url}">
```

This will ensure that if your context path is added to the url.

Comment: Which `jstl` version should I download ? and after that , just add the line `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>` at the head (first line) of `index.jsp` ?

Comment: jstl 1.2, you can download from here - http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=javax/servlet/jstl/1.2/jstl-1.2.jar, and yes add that declaration at the top of the jsp file

Comment: You're suggesting a completely outdated JSTL URI. Please read our JSTL wiki page for the proper guide: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info Apart from that, this is does not answer the concrete problem in any way.

Comment: Oh, thanks did not realize that the jstl link was outdated. Yes the suggestion does not fix the underlying issue, was speculating that this could be one of the reasons why the servlet was not being found. +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If any error occurred while instantiating servlet we will get this type of error,
even if libraries missing in `WEB-INF\lib` folder. Make sure all the libraries are be placed in `WEB-INF\lib`.