# HTTP Status 404 - /liangweb/TimeForm

Tags: tomcat, servlets

i have just started working with tomcat and servlet. after running some html page i was trying to run this timeform.it's giving me page.but when i click on submit page it give me this error instead of time.please help me.

```
    import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;

public class TimeForm extends HttpServlet {
  private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html";
  private Locale[] allLocale = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
  private String[] allTimeZone = TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();

  /** Process the HTTP Get request */
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
      response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<h3>Choose locale and time zone</h3>");
    out.println("<form method=\"post\" action=" +
      "/liangweb/TimeForm>");
    out.println("Locale <select size=\"1\" name=\"locale\">");

    // Fill in all locales
    for (int i = 0; i < allLocale.length; i++) {
      out.println("<option value=\"" + i +"\">" +
        allLocale[i].getDisplayName() + "</option>");
    }
    out.println("</select>");

    // Fill in all time zones
    out.println("<p>Time Zone<select size=\"1\" name=\"timezone\">");
    for (int i = 0; i < allTimeZone.length; i++) {
      out.println("<option value=\"" + allTimeZone[i] +"\">" +
        allTimeZone[i] + "</option>");
    }
    out.println("</select>");
    out.println("<p><input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" >");
    out.println("<input type=\"reset\" value=\"Reset\"></p>");
    out.println("</form>");
    out.close(); // Close stream
  }

  /** Process the HTTP Post request */
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
      response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html>");
    int localeIndex = Integer.parseInt(
      request.getParameter("locale"));
    String timeZoneID = request.getParameter("timezone");
    out.println("<head><title>Current Time</title></head>");
    out.println("<body>");
    Calendar calendar =
      new GregorianCalendar(allLocale[localeIndex]);
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneID);
    DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(
      DateFormat.FULL, DateFormat.FULL, allLocale[localeIndex]);
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(timeZone);
    out.println("Current time is " +
      dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime()) + "</p>");
    out.println("</body></html>");
    out.close(); // Close stream
  }
}
```

then i have compiled it without error `javac -cp .;d:\apache\lib\servlet-api.jar TimeForm.java`
this is my web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app version="3.0"
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">



   <servlet>
      <servlet-name>servertime</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>TimeForm</servlet-class>
   </servlet>

   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>servertime</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/servertime</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

error after clicking on submit-

type Status report

message /liangweb/TimeForm

description The requested resource is not available.

Comment: `out.println("<form method=\"post\" action=" + "/liangweb/TimeForm>");`. You're missing quotes around the `action` value

Comment: out.println("<form method=\"post\" "action"=" +
      "/liangweb/TimeForm>");

like this.?

Comment: No, that is not the value. The value is to the right side of the `=`. Look at how you did everything else. Maybe the `+` is confusing you. The `"` you current;y have is just plain String starting/terminating quotes. You still need another set of quotes. Take out the `+` and make it like everything else. Maybe you can see it better

Comment: out.println("<form method=\"post\" action=" /liangweb/TimeForm">");

is this correct..sorry but...this is my first program

Comment: `action=\"" + "/liangweb/TimeForm\">"`

Comment: what is the diff, between that  "/ and \" is this for directory ..?

Comment: You need the back slash to escape the `"` character inside Strings, just like you're doing in everything else

Comment: no its not working..still same error
my dir.is like this....is that any problem with that.?.what is liangweb anyways
D:\apache\webapps\cs532\WEB-INF\classes

Comment: Use `servertime` instead of `TimeForm` in your path. `servertime` is the url mapping. Same url you use to get the form, is the same you will post to the form

Comment: omg........finallly.......thnx bro.....:DD:D:D:D:DD:D:
3> 3>3 >

ty for help man......it works now

Answer (score 0):

form method=\"post\" action = \"" + "/cs532/servertime \"

This must be helpful  and perfect solution.