# Under web .xml /welcome file index.jsp written but not getting output

Tags: java, user-interface, web, tomcat6

I am trying to develop one web application using Java,Eclipse,Tomcat server 6.
Everything is fine ,but the issue is when I am running the project on server it shows http status 404 :the requested resource is not available ..whereas in web .xml under index.jsp  is available 
Also index.jsp is not under WEB-INF folder.It is under WebContebt folder .
Also servlet and servlet mapping is written along with the url patterns for the projects 
So after container startup it must read web.xml,in which welcome file is listed ,but it's not finding out and showing Http status 404-the requested resource not available

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Status 404 - Servlet \[ServletName\] is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293325/http-status-404-servlet-servletname-is-not-available)

Comment: Requested resource is not available which means during container startup only its not reading index .jsp..why is it so ?why web.xml is not read by container