# Servlet: HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, servlets, netbeans

My Servlet doesn't work at all. I'm getting HTTPS Status 404- Not Found. Below is the complete code for the same:-

index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
          <head>
              <title>Page title</title>
              <meta charset="UTF-8" />
         <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
         <link href="CSS/cssSheet.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
     </head>
     <body>

         <nav>
             <a href="ControlleurSimple?action=apropos" target="_self">A propos</a>
         </nav>

         <main>
             <h1>Welcome</h1>
             Text here

         </main>
    </body>
 </html>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>ControllerSimple</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>WebApplication1.ControllerSimple</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ControllerSimple</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/ControllerSimple</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

ControllerSimple.java

```
package WebApplication1;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class ControllerSimple extends HttpServlet {

    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
            /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet ControllerSimple</title>");            
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet ControllerSimple at " + request.getContextPath() + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String action = request.getParameter("action");
String jspPage = "/index.html";
if ((action == null) || (action.length() < 1)) {
 action = "default";
}
if ("apropos".equals(action)) {
 jspPage = "/apropos.jsp";
}
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher(jspPage);
rd.forward(request, response);

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

apropos.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <link href="CSS/cssSheet.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />

    </head>
    <body>

        <main>
            Text

        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm new to the servlet, so maybe I would have missed something. When I click on the link, I have the "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found " error. I really don't understand what I did wrong.

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2 and GlassFish 4.1.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Status 404 - Servlet \[ServletName\] is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11293325/http-status-404-servlet-servletname-is-not-available)

Comment: Have you deployed your Web-App in GlassFish properly? Is your Web server up & running? Did you try cleaning out the Project?

Comment: Voting to close for typo: `ControlleurSimple`!= `ControllerSimple`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the code snippet, You have a typo mistake. There, you have to change `ControlleurSimple` to `ControllerSimple`.

Comment: I don't see any typo... Can you be a bit more precice when you say "code snippet"? What code are you talking about? (:

Comment: ControlleurSimple?action=apropos