# Eclipse Tomcat v8.0 404 Error

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I'm trying to follow this tutorial and create a simple "Dynamic Web Project" in Eclipse (Mars): 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYc3FjhMMzI
The project contains: aboutus.jsp, login.jsp, videos.jsp, welcome.jsp, Login.java(Servlet)

I'm running on port 8081 because 8080 was already used.

If I set the location for Tomcat in "General" properties to: [workspace metadata] per this thread:
[TOMCAT - HTTP Status 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340711/tomcat-http-status-404?noredirect=1&lq=1)
The server will start and browser (Firefox 57.0.4) will launch but I'll recieve a "404" error.

If I set the location for Tomcat in "General" properties to: /Servers/Tomcat v8.0 Server at location.server by pressing the "Switch Location" button
and in the "Overview" for Tomcat set "Use Tomcat installation (takes control of Tomcat installation)" per this thread:
[Tomcat started in Eclipse but unable to connect to http://localhost:8085/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280064/tomcat-started-in-eclipse-but-unable-to-connect-to-http-localhost8085?rq=1)
then the server won't launch and I'll get the error message:

'Starting Tomcat Server v8.0 Server at localhost' has encountered a problem.
Server Tomcat at localhost failed to start.

When I press the "Details" button, I just get:
"Server Tomcat v8.0 Server at localhost failed to start."

I recieve the following in the console:

> WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context}
>   Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:LoginModule'
>   did not find a matching property.
>
> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/LoginModule]]
>
> SEVERE: A child container failed during start
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
>
> SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is
>   unable to start. org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to
>   start component [StandardServer[8005]]
>
> SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler
>   ["http-nio-8081"] java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler
>   ["ajp-nio-8009"] java.lang.NullPointerException

The following line in my: aboutus.jsp, login.jsp, videos.jsp and welcome.jsp is NOT being syntax colored.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
```

I pressed: ctrl + chift + f
to format those files as html but whenever I close and reopen the project they return to 
unformatted.

---

- Running on localhost:8081
- Windows 7 Home Premium service pack 1
- Eclipse: Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2) Build id: 20160218-0600
- Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools: 3.7.0.v201602161354
- Apache Tomcat Version 8.0.48   (C:\Program Files)
- Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.7.v201511240257
- JST Server Adapters 3.2.400.v201503102136
- JST Server Adapters Extensions 3.3.401.v201508232356
- JST Server UI 3.4.200.v201512031711
- JST Core 3.4.200.v201512031711
- jdk1.8.0_151
- Firefox 57.0.4

Comment: You need to look at the backtraces in the log and see why tomcat is failing to start.

Comment: Do you mean the Tomcat log or Eclipse workspace log?

Comment: Did you try to deploy the application directly under $CATALINA_HOME/webapps without using eclipde?

Answer (score 0):

Changing Tomcat permissions as suggested in the first answer to this post worked for me:

[Error in publishing the configuration in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18333739/error-in-publishing-the-configuration-in-eclipse/37248143)