# Login issue to Tomcat server status and manager app

Tags: tomcat, server

I still can't login to server status after editing the user roles

here is my tomcat-users.xml

```
'<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
 <role rolename="manager-script"/>
 <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
 <role rolename="manager-status"/>
 <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
 <role rolename="admin-script"/>

 <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="manager-status, manager-gui, manager-script, manager-jmx,admin-gui, admin-script"/>'
```

what is problem ??

Comment: are using eclipse  to run server ?

Comment: yes I'm using Eclipse @yugi

Comment: try to run server using command prompt and check

Comment: Thanks man, it works but what if I wanted to run it from Eclipse ? I'm still facing the problem @yugi

Answer (score 0):

in case of running tomcat  from Eclipse.you should change the setting of server .u can follow below link

[stackoverfloow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2280064/tomcat-started-in-eclipse-but-unable-to-connect-to-http-localhost8085)

Comment: Unfortunately its all the same, though I'm having those settings by default.

Comment: you modified the  setting of  tomcat server in eclipse ?after changing setting can u restart system or stop server and start again .may be it will help you